# Refresh a widget programmatically

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm developing an app in Flutter, and I'm stuck with this: I have a list of widgets that I generate dynamically. When I press a button, I need to show or hide one of the widgets in the list. I use the `Visible` widget to show or hide them.

The problem is that I need to know how to update any of the specific widgets in my widget list as they are dynamic and are separated, it is getting complicated doing int programmatically.

How can I do it?

PS: I have the same app developed in Android Studio and I do it by traversing for example the child Views of a `LinearLayout` and then I ask for its id programmatically.

Comment: If it's within the same widget, use setState().  If they are close enough to each other, you can pass a callback to trigger, although that's somewhat bad form.  Or, you can have the widget depend on something in appstate, using some state management solution. (I recommend RiverPod.)

Comment: add to previous comment if its outside you can replace the future call to a separate variable and pass the same and whenever you want to refresh update the value of the future see example here in my project https://github.com/bibek-ranjan-saha/prodt_test/blob/master/lib/screens/home_page.dart line number -146

Comment: @RandalSchwartz unfortunately, there is not in the same widget :(. I will check RiverPod for the appstate. Thank you for your reply!.